# Splitting dataframes based on a cell string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column Colour which contains the string either "Red" or "Blue". Is it possible to split the dataframe every time the Colour column is equal to "Blue". Please find the example dataframes and desired output below. DF is the initial dataframe. Res1, Res2, Res3 are what I want. Thanks in advance.

df:

```
     Colour
 0    Red
 1    Red
 2    Red
 3    Blue
 4    Red
 5    Blue
 6    Red
 7    Red
 8    Red
 9    Red
 10   Blue
```

res1:

```
    Colour
 0    Red
 1    Red
 2    Red
 3    Blue
```

res2:

```
    Colour
 0    Red
 1    Blue
```

res3:

```
   Colour
 0    Red
 1    Red
 2    Red
 3    Red
 4   Blue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `groupby()` on `cumsum`. Since you want the marker `Blue` at the end, we need a shift:

```
for i, d in df.groupby(df['Colour'].shift().eq('Blue').cumsum()):
    print(d)
```

A dictionary is best to store this in a data structure:

```
d = {k:d for k,d in df.groupby(df['Colour'].shift().eq('Blue').cumsum())}
```

and `d[0]` gives:

```
  Colour
0    Red
1    Red
2    Red
3   Blue
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try `cumsum` with reverse the order

```
s = df.Colour.eq('Blue').iloc[::-1].cumsum()
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby(s)))
d[1]
Out[89]: 
   Colour
6     Red
7     Red
8     Red
9     Red
10   Blue
```