# Splitting dataframes based on numerous cell strings

Tags: python, pandas

I recently posted a question about how to split a dataframe based on a cell string: [Splitting dataframes based on a cell string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64376793/splitting-dataframes-based-on-a-cell-string)

I now want to use this same logic, but also split it further so that the first row is either orange or green, and the last row will be blue. Please see my example below:

I have a dataframe with a column Colour which contains the string either "Red", "Orange", "Green" or "Blue". Is it possible to split the dataframe every time the Colour column is equal to "Blue", and the first row should be either "Orange" or "Green". Please find the example dataframes and desired output below. DF is the initial dataframe. Res1, Res2, Res3 are what I want. Thanks in advance.

df:

```
    Colour
 0    Red
 1    Orange
 2    Red
 3    Blue
 4    Green
 5    Blue
 6    Red
 7    Orange
 8    Orange
 9    Red
 10   Blue
```

res1:

```
     Colour
 0    Orange
 1    Red
 2    Blue
```

res2:

```
      Colour
 0    Green
 1    Blue
```

res3:

```
     Colour
 0    Orange
 1    Red
 2    Blue
```

Note: I changed the desired output. The result should print the latest occurrence of Orange/Green as the first row, and Blue as the last. So in this case, index 7 is not included as Orange is also in index 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick modification of the accepted answer in the linked question:

```
d = {k:d.loc[(d.Colour.isin(['Orange','Green'])).cumsum().idxmax():] 
     for k,d in df.groupby(df['Colour'].shift().eq('Blue').cumsum())}

# print output
for k,v in d.items():
    print('='*10, k)
    print(v)
```

Output:

```
========== 0
   Colour
1  Orange
2     Red
3    Blue
========== 1
  Colour
4  Green
5   Blue
========== 2
    Colour
8   Orange
9      Red
10    Blue
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Apologies it didn't actually solve my issue fully. I have edited the question above. I want the latest occurrence of Orange/Green to be the first row. So ideally there should be one instance of Orange/Green and Blue in every dataframe.

Comment: @toothsie Updated the answer.